# MongoDB: Is there a way to find documents & set a value in them in the same operation?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a collection called "messages". Each message has a 'read' boolean value. In some instances when I retrieve the messages, I'd like to set the value to 'true', while returning the pre-modified value.

So, let's say I have 1 message, whose 'read' value is 'false'. When I retrieve it, I'd like to return the initial 'false' value, but in the same operation I'd like to set it to 'true'.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: Also, read carefully about the multiupdates and just the chapter about the updates itself. It contains lots of notable information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`findAndModify` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) is what you're looking for:

> 4 . The command returns the original unmodified document selected for this update.

If you were using it in the Mongo shell, your usage would look like:

```
db.messages.findAndModify({query: {read: false}, update: {read: true}})
```

It looks like you're using Java, though. The Java driver offers a few different signatures for `findAndModify()`. You can check them out in the [javadoc for DBCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html).

Comment: I jumped the gun -- this method only allows to modify one document, and return it. I needed something that would do bulk updates/retrieves...

Comment: When you said "I have 1 message" I thought you were working with individual documents. MongoDB doesn't support `findAndModify` for bulk operations.